# Interpreting parallel trends (Diff-in-Diff)

Tags: regression, modeling, econometrics, panel-data, difference-in-difference

I am evaluating the impact of a capital gains tax hike that was implemented in certain states, but not others, using a Diff-in-Diff method.

However, I am not sure how to define my treatment time, and whether it should be based on the policy's implementation date or the policy's announcement. Specifically, I have read that with capital gains taxation, individuals may respond and alter their investing behavior as soon as a tax hike is anticipated or announced, and I was wondering if I should use the policy announcement as my treatment time?

Below are two parallel trends graphs showing the change in Y, before and after the policy and between treated vs. control states.

If my interpretation is correct below, then using the policy's announcement date as the treatment time, we can see that stock prices declined more drastically, compared to the graph using policy implementation as my treatment time, is that correct?

And does that mean that policy announcement date should be used as the treatment time?

The graphs were produced with Stata with this code:

```
ssc install diff
                                           
* Create a binary variable to indicate the time of policy implementation: 2007m8.
gen treatment_time = (time>=ym(2007, 8) & !missing(time))
```

Running the Did model:

```
didregress (stock price) (DiD_implementation), group(treated) time(treatment_time )
estat trendplots
```

[[image: ![Policy] Implementation][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6azl.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6azl.png)

[image]

Comment: Just curious, but what software package are you using to estimate these graphs, if any? And how many time periods do you have before the announcement of the tax hike?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post with the Stata code to produce the graphs. I am using monthly data and I have approximately 70 months pre policy announcement.

Comment: It seems to me that the treatment_time is incorrect in this case. It should be the real time